# Add Autocomplete on Tabular Form

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle-apex

I need add Auto complete on apex Tabular Form. there is a `column` as `description` and i need to add Auto complete to that column. how could i do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer for my own question.

http://htmldb.oracle.com/pls/otn/f?p=31517:178:563249139500301::NO